# why is tooltip not binding link title data in ngRepeat, Adding the class but with ngHide

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

Can someone help with the problem i have with title of my link element, am trying to bind data from a json file and add some info to tooltip using ng-repeat but the tooltip is not showing when i hover the link it adding the tooltip but with class="tooltip in ng scope am fade ng hide" the other link element with the same data binding out the loop is showing the tooltip.

Here is the code:

```js
//this is the directive

var testDirective = function(){
    return{
        restrict:'AE',
        template: '\
                      <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="plan in product.includedplan" >\
                      <div>\
                      <a href="#" bs-tooltip="tooltip" title="" title="{{plan.featureDes}}" data-placement="right" class="included_Features">{{plan.featureName}}</a>\
                      </div>\
                      </div>',
         controller:'testCtrl'        
    };
}

//this line is working
<a href="#" bs-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="included_Features" title="Include:{{product.plan}}">{{product.plan}}</a>



//this line is not
<div test-directive> </div>
```

Comment: Because the HTML that is being generated from the template directive, is not evaluated after and thus the bs-tooltip directive isn't picked up. I'm affraid I don't know the solution though, since I struggled with a similair problem. - We applied an ugly jQuery hack when the data changed to find the elements and then set the tooltip through code.

Comment: @spike if it's a jQuery plugin you can initialize in the link function of element. In this case it isn't clear if tooltip is jQuery or angular directive

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! So that's what larry can do too, right? Because that's bs-tooltip is an angular-strap directive, which works on some twitter bootstrap function which is some jQuery I think.

Comment: @spike if it's already an angular directive (like angular-strap) it should work. Directive templates get compiled by angular and can contain other directives

Comment: @charlietfl hmm.. thanks again. Then I'm out of ideas except 'maybe something wrong with the directive'. Indeed, I had directives inside directives obviously. But indeed - I did have troubles with the Boostrap tooltip on elements produced by ng-repeat.

Comment: A demo replicating problem would defintiely help

Comment: thanks guys for the comment, it funny tho that when i pass a string to the title attr it displays it but won`t display data binding